# Which JavaScript Array functions are mutating?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mutable

I am writing an Array-derived class in JavaScript and need to know which functions to overload so that I can be aware of changes made to the array.

I know `Array.push()` and `Array.splice()` are mutating. Is there a definitive list of any others?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remember if a method mutates the original array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54836118/how-to-remember-if-a-method-mutates-the-original-array)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You can find the list on MDN as [Mutator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype#Mutator_methods) methods (along with [Accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype#Accessor_methods) and [Iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype#Iteration_methods) methods):

- [`copyWithin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/copyWithin)
- [`fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)
- [`pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)
- [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)
- [`reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)
- [`shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)
- [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
- [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)
- [`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)

Comment: Mutator link is currently incorrect, it is now: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype#Mutator_methods

Comment: @zamnuts Thanks. And, looks like all the links needed some updating.

Comment: looks like the mutator method list was removed from MDN docs. see this SO answer instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54836218/1481489

Answer (score 10):

I found this website called [Doesitmutate](https://doesitmutate.xyz/)

Have the list of all functions - and tells whether it mutates or not.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use `.concat()`, before using your mutation method, to ensure you are not mutating your arrays, eg

```
const dontMutateMe = [4,5,1,2,3];
const sortArray = dontMutateMe.concat().sort(...)
```

Comment: With ES2015 it's just: `const sortArray = [ ...dontMutateMe ].sort(...);`

Comment: As nice as ES6 is, ES6 is not always available, luckily concat is. 
Good to know concat works well in those cases.

Just remember, it is not always best to create a whole new array to do basic operations, there is a cost to copying.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong @jasonleonhard, but woudln't `const sortArray = dontMutateMe.concat()` create a new array just as `const sortArray = [ ...dontMutateMe ]` would?