# javascript: List of array methods that change the array they were applied to

Tags: javascript

I constantly have problem with keeping this in my head, and I can't google it out quickly. That's why I'm putting this question here.

Every time I'm calling a method like `concat`, `sort` or `slice`, I'm asking myself: does it create and return a new array, or it just modifies and returns array it was applied to?

**Q**: could you please list methods that change the original array vs methods that construct and return a new array?

Methods like `pop` or `push` are not in the game, it's obvious what they do.

Comment: MDN lists `Array` methods grouped under [Mutator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Mutator_methods), [Accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Accessor_methods), and [Iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Iteration_methods).

Comment: Also, this is a likely duplicate of [Which JavaScript Array functions are mutating?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9009879).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which JavaScript Array functions are mutating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009879/which-javascript-array-functions-are-mutating)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The full list of methods on array instances that change the values or number of values in the array is this one:

- `Array.prototype.push`
- `Array.prototype.pop`
- `Array.prototype.shift`
- `Array.prototype.unshift`
- `Array.prototype.splice`
- `Array.prototype.reverse`
- `Array.prototype.sort`
- `Array.prototype.fill`
- `Array.prototype.copyWithin`

Aditionally, changing the `length` property can remove elements from the array (if you decrease it) or add undefined items to the array (if you increase it).

Finally, changing the properties of the arrays with keys that are positive integer-like strings like `'0'`,`'1'`, `'3000'`, etc will change the values at those indexes and possibly increase the length of the array.