# Why do JavaScript functions work at different times?

Tags: javascript

Bit of a weird title, let me explain.

Take this:

```
let a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
function joining(){
    console.log(a.join())
}
joining() // a,b,c
THE ABOVE IS JOINED

function joining(){
    a.join()
    console.log(a)
}
joining() // ['a', 'b', 'c']
THE ABOVE IS NOT JOINED

function pushing(){
    a.push('d')
    console.log(a)
}
pushing() // ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
THE ABOVE IS PUSHED
```

The first `joining()` joins them correctly as I have called `.join()` on the array.
However, the second one I have called joined on it and then tried to log it but it displays the original. 
However I did exactly the same with the `push()` method and that changed the original array. how can I tell what methods will change the original array and which wont or is it just a case of learning each method?

Comment: In second example do `a = a.join()`

Comment: [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join?v=control) doesn't modify the original value.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009879/which-javascript-array-functions-are-mutating

Comment: @Pyromonk that's my question. do i need to learn each individual method to see if it alters the original or not?

Comment: @Theworm2 You can't alter an array into a string, they're completely different types.

Comment: push() will modify your original array

Comment: @Theworm2, yes. That's usually the case with predefined functions in any programming language.

Comment: @georg cheers, that is helpful regarding mutator methods

Comment: @Theworm2 Only arrays and objects can be mutated. So any function that returns some other type can't possibly alter the original to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that `a.join()` does not output your expected result in the second instance is because you have not assigned the returned value from the invocation of the method.

```
a = a.join();
console.log(a);
```

For completeness, in your first example the expected output is logged on the console because the returned value from the invocation is passed as a parameter to `console.log()`.

Answer (score 1):

The join() method joins the elements of an array into a string, and returns the string.

Therefore, you should update it into:

```
a = a.join()
```