# How To Mutate Array Of Objects In Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am trying to mutate my array after updating objects with the new values. Currently when I use `splice()` it has been for only mutating single object. Perhaps I am looking for simple javascript method but I am trying to figure out how mutate array if I am updating multiple objects simultaneously?

This is the store action I am using to `commit` response.data

```
updateCheckedEngagements(context, checkedEnagements) {  
      axios.patch('/engagementsarray', {
        engagements: checkedEnagements.engagements,
        assigned_to: checkedEnagements.assigned_to,
        status: checkedEnagements.status
      })
      .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data)
          context.commit('updateCheckedEngagements', response.data)
      })
      .catch(error => {
          console.log(error.response.data)
      })           
    },
```

here is the mutation I have currently set up but I do not think it is correct

```
    updateCheckedEngagements(state, engagement) {
          const index = state.engagements.findIndex(item => item.id == engagement.id);
          state.engagements.splice(index, 1, {
            'id': engagement.id,
            'assigned_to': engagement.assigned_to,
            'status': engagement.status,
          })
        },
```

Also since I am passing `checkedEngagements` as my parameter in the store action, does that also have to be the 2nd parameter for the mutation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expect to update multiple objects simultaneously, value argument provided in mutation (`engagement` in code above), should be an array.

We can return new state of `engagements` with updated values with following code, as an example:

```
const actions = {
  updateCheckedEngagements(state, updatedEngagements = []) {
    // Create list of ids, to simplify index matching
    const ids = updatedEngagements.map(engagement => engagement.id)
    state.engagements = state.engagements.map(engagement => {
      // Check if updated engagement matches currently iterated one
      const matchedIndex = ids.indexOf(engagement.id)
      // If index matches, we shall replace current item with updated values
      if (matchedIndex !== -1) {
        return {
          ...updatedEngagements[matchedIndex]
        }
      }
      // Return previous value by default
      return engagement
    })
  }
}
```

It is a good practice to avoid using [array mutating methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009879/which-javascript-array-functions-are-mutating) inside mutations to ensure that state watchers will be notified and reactivity works as expected: all state values are updated and getters recomputed.

Comment: Thank you!! I have been trying to figure this out for a couple days, I was no where close to this solution. Thank you again! I did not know I could pass an argument such as `updatedEngagements = []` and then `return` it like that