# How to remember if a method mutates the original array?

Tags: javascript, methods

I know I can find a list of mutator methods on MDN, still, in practice I always forget if methods like push() or reverse() mutates the original array or creates a new one. Is there a logic to why certain methods are mutators and some are non-mutators, so I can easily remember?

Comment: That's a valid concern and no concrete solution. When I write a functional program that deals with arrays, I'll copy the input and use the copy instead. `const array = [...]`, `let copy = [...array]`.

Comment: making copies before understanding where they are necessary is a pitfall. I cannot think of the last time I have made an entire copy of an array and I don't use mutating methods.

Answer (score 12):

Maybe a helpful way to remember them is to identify the mutating methods and group them; there's only a small amount.

*Add/remove from array:*

- `Array.prototype.fill()` - overwrite elements anywhere
- `Array.prototype.pop()` - remove from right
- `Array.prototype.push()` - add to right
- `Array.prototype.shift()` - remove from left
- `Array.prototype.unshift()` - add to left
- `Array.prototype.splice()` - add/remove anywhere

*Rearrange arrays:*

- `Array.prototype.sort()` - rearrange elements using a sorting function
- `Array.prototype.reverse()` - reverse elements

*Oddball:*

- `Array.prototype.copyWithin()` - honestly, I've never used this method

---

**List of mutating array methods**

- `Array.prototype.copyWithin()`
- `Array.prototype.fill()`
- `Array.prototype.pop()`
- `Array.prototype.push()`
- `Array.prototype.reverse()`
- `Array.prototype.shift()`
- `Array.prototype.sort()`
- `Array.prototype.splice()`
- `Array.prototype.unshift()`

**List of non-mutating array methods**

- `Array.from()` - create an array from an iterable
- `Array.isArray()` - check if a variable is an array
- `Array.of()` - create an array; function version of `[]`
- `Array.prototype.concat()` - combine several arrays into a new single array
- `Array.prototype.entries()` - get iterator of key/value pairs
- `Array.prototype.every()` - check if every value matches a function
- `Array.prototype.filter()` - create an array of values matching a filter
- `Array.prototype.find()` - find a value using a function
- `Array.prototype.findIndex()` - find the index of a value using a function
- `Array.prototype.flat()` - flatten a nested array
- `Array.prototype.flatMap()` - create an new array using a mapping function
- `Array.prototype.forEach()` - run a side effect for each value
- `Array.prototype.includes()` - check if the array includes a value
- `Array.prototype.indexOf()` - find the index of a value by value
- `Array.prototype.join()` - combine values into a string using a separator
- `Array.prototype.keys()` - get iterator of keys
- `Array.prototype.lastIndexOf()` - find the index of a value by value, starting at the end
- `Array.prototype.map()` - create a new array using a mapping function
- `Array.prototype.reduce()` - fold over each value, producing a new value
- `Array.prototype.reduceRight()` - fold over each value, starting from the right, producing a new value
- `Array.prototype.slice()` - select a subarray
- `Array.prototype.some()` - check if some value matches a function
- `Array.prototype.toLocaleString()` - string representation of the array, uses `toLocaleString` on values
- `Array.prototype.toString()` - string representation of the array, uses `toString` on values
- `Array.prototype.values()` - get iterator of values
- `Array.prototype[@@iterator]()` - get default iterator

Comment: The edit queue is full, so I'm gonna point out some corrections here:
`Array.prototype.pop()` - removes *last element*
`Array.prototype.push()` - adds element on *last position*
`Array.prototype.shift()` - removes *first element*
`Array.prototype.unshift()` - inserts element *at first position*

Comment: @Dami "first" and "last" are relative and can mean different things in different implementations. i chose "left" and "right" because javascript is a left-to-right language and so arrays are expressed `[left, ...to, right]`.

Answer (score 1):

Any method that causes the indices to shift, diminish or grow, or otherwise changes the original definition of the list, by nature, must be mutable.  A mnemonic might be to consider if you *want something from* the array or *want to do something* to the array?  Shift and pop are arguably confusing because they don't really have an equivalent immutable convenience method like say 'top' or 'last'.

Comment: Now we have Array.at(-1)  for last